# Is it possible to color-code the output of apt?

Tags: command-line, apt, colors

With the plethora of possibilities for most command-line tools, I would be surprised to learn that there is no way to colorize the info that apt-get, apt-cache, and related tools return. Even so, Googling was fruitless in this.

Primarily, it would be nice to have the summary lines that show total count/size, and color-code each type of action count: eg, upgrades in blue, installs in green, held in yellow, and removed in red.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's easy. There are even tools for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighting

I prefer `rcg` (Regex Colored Glasses).

Answer (score 4):

As weird as it may sound: NO. While the excellent Arch Linux's pacman has built-in colorizing capabilities (and a few more available via 3rd-party wrappers) there's nothing similar for the aging apt/dpkg combo nor the relatively newer aptitude tool.

This is how pacman looks like using an external wrapper (mostly Yaourt or Packer, can't remember which one I was using at the time):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/17FqT.png

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you can get:
[How do I enable fancy apt colours and progress bars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars)

For the rest you can use sed/awk and terminal color codes.