# How do I enable fancy apt colours and progress bars?

Tags: apt

I've heard that apt has a new fancy colour and progress bar feature, but that I have to manually enable it.

How do I do this?

Comment: a quick add to let users know that you can use this out of the box with no further configuration required. Colours and progress bar enabled by default, just use `apt` instead of `apt-get`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### For 14.04 and newer:

Make a file in: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```

Then add these contents:

```
Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";
```

And save the file.

Then if your `umask` was not 0027, (i.e. it might also be 0023), then also set this new file's permissions to 644 (i.e. -rw-r--r--) as follows:

```
$ chmod 644 99progressbar
```

(Without this permission correction things like Debian's `reportbug` will stop working.)

Now enjoy apt progress bars in all their glory:

[image]

You can use them with these commands for a nice new apt experience:

```
apt update
apt install
apt upgrade
```

Run `apt` by itself for the list of commands. Colors are enabled by default for `apt`, and do not affect `apt-get`.

#### Colors:

You can also tweak the color of the progress bar by adding this as well:

```
Dpkg::Progress-Fancy::Progress-Bg "%1b[40m";
```

The colors are based on ANSI Color codes, look at [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) as a reference.

#### Sources:

- Michael Vogt's [blogpost](http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0) on apt 1.0

Comment: I am still using 13.10 (at least for the next week or two). Is this feature available in 13.10?

Comment: I am reasonably certain it is not in 13.10.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to using apt instead of apt-get, etc?

Comment: That is a bit odd. I get the progress bar on apt-get upgrade, install and remove, but no colors in apt-get update, I have to use apt update. Very odd.

Comment: Hm. I'm on 13.10 and after applying this settings i see progress in both apt and apt-get as well as in dpkg.

Comment: What about 12.04? I've added a PPA to upgrade to the newest apt, but still can't see the color.

Comment: @snowhawkyrf Depends what PPA you've added. Also, are you using `apt-get` or just `apt`?

Comment: @Seth I've tried the ppa:mvo/apt-src-ftparchive and added the 99progressbar file, now I can see the bar! Thanks.

Comment: @mikeymop no, apt is the more user-friendly version of apt-get. They both offer essentially the same functionality.

Answer (score 6):

The `-o` option allows to change the behavior temporarily. I described it [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-studio-users/2016-August/010926.html):

> It's just not an apt-get default, but also available for apt-get, run
>   it with
>
> ```
> -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="1"
> ```
>
> for example
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="1" install alpine-pico
> ```

Answer (score 5):

## For default colors

In addition to Jorge Castro's excellent answer, you can add an extra line to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar` file:

```
Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";
APT::Color "1";
```

This will enable the default colors for `apt`.  I found it by accident while reading the `apt` `man` page:

> The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need to be backward compatible like apt-get(8). Therefore some options are different:
>
> - The option DPkgPM::Progress-Fancy is enabled.
> - The option APT::Color is enabled.

Comment: How can I change apt colour from dark green to yellow or any other?