# Progress bar while using apt

Tags: apt

I have downloaded the install-progress.cc file which is the same as [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/apt/trusty/view/head:/apt-pkg/install-progress.cc#L233).

I have tried following [these](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar) and even [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars) instructions to enable the progress bar in the terminal, but even if I run `apt` processes I don't get the progress bar.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar`? That's the only file which is required to be edited to enable progress bars..

Comment: In my case the last line of the updating thing which shows the percentage and the website which it is accessing and stuff turns yellow. But that's pretty much it. If I stop it with ^C everything after that turns yellow. No progress bar.

Comment: It goes like this: `Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";`
<next line> `Dpkg::Progress-Fancy::Progress-Bg "%1b[40m";`

Comment: I got the progress bar while using apt-get! Is that where I'm supposed to get it?

Comment: I get the progress bars for both `apt` and `apt-get`. So, since you are getting the progress bars, problem solved for you?

Comment: Actually, I thought the progress bar appears even while updating the repos. Does it appear only when installing something? Or all the time?

Comment: It appears for me while updating the repos as well.. for both `apt-get update` and `apt update`...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14260/discussion-between-chinmaya-k-r-and-aditya)