# Use apt progress bar in custom scripts

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I like the apt progress bar in Ubuntu 16.04. Can I use this in my own bash scripts?

This question is about reusing the code in the apt progress bar, not implementing something similar. I know how to create other progress bars.

This is the progress bar I'm talking about:
[How do I enable fancy apt colours and progress bars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars)

Comment: Presumably something with https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.progress.text.html

Answer (score 1):

**Check the source code for progress_bar in the below git repository**

https://github.com/Kiran-Bose/supreme

Also try the custom bash script package:

**Install deb file from above repository**

Functionality overview

(1)Open Apps
----Firefox
----Calculator
----Settings

(2)Manage Files
----Search
----Navigate
----Quick access

```
            |----Select File(s)
            |----Inverse Selection
            |----Make directory
            |----Make file
                                          |----Open
                                          |----Copy
                                          |----Move
                                          |----Delete
                                          |----Rename
                                          |----Send to Device
                                          |----Properties
```

(3)Manage Phone
----Move/Copy from phone
----Move/Copy to phone
----Sync folders

(4)Manage USB
----Move/Copy from USB
----Move/Copy to USB